# Function that returns elements of a list repeated N times

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I need to write a function `rep(lst, k)` where `lst` is a list of integers and `k` is the number of times they occur. For example, if i have a list:

```
lst = [1,2,1,5,3,4,2,1,3,5,6]
```

and launch the command `rep(lst,2)`, it needs to return a list without repetitions that contain the numbers repeated k times, like:

```
rep(lst, 2)
# returns  [1,2,5,3]
```

How do i do this? i can write a function where i count the occurence of a specific variable, but i can't do this, counting only returns me the number of elements in the list.

Comment: format your question to make it *interesting-looking* and add your attempt to make it *help-attracting*

Comment: why is 1 returned as it appears 3 times in the lst

Comment: `[k for k,v in Counter(lst).items() if v == 2]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `sets` for the task:

```
lst = [1,2,1,5,3,4,2,1,3,5,6]

def rep(the_list, rep):
  return [x for x in set(the_list) if the_list.count(x) == rep]

print(rep(lst, 2))  # -> [2, 3, 5]
```

1. `set(the_list)` the list is converted to set to make sure every *unique* element is only searched once.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for! I thought the set module was only for removing repeating occurences, didn't know it could also be used to count.

Comment: I am using it to remove repeating occurences.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution using counters

```
from collections import Counter

def count(list, k):
    tmp = Counter(list)
    return [x for x in tmp if tmp[x] == k]
```